# How to updating the objects of a map in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a map which has a bunch of integers,vector and a map.

```
class testMap
{
    int var1;
    int var2;
    ........
    .......
    int var50; //variables up to 50
    map  objmap;
    int *ptr
    vector<myClass> vecObj; //vector of myClass objects
}
typedef std::map<string , testMap> eeMap; //global map
eeMap tMap;
```

Assuming I created add one entry using map insert tMap.insert(make_pair ("test", *ptrTestMap ) ); how do I update the object in this global map via a function.

This new object might have only one variable changed or it can be multiple.

```
void UpdateTestMap(testMap newTestMapValue,string key)
{
```

//`enter code here`

```
}

Option#1: Have a overloaded assignment operator 
Option#2 Compare the members one by one and overwrite the variables that are changed.
Option#3 Erase the key and insert it again with the same key and the new object.
##Any other option
```

I appreciate what would be the best option of doing this?.

Comment: If you have no threads, use `tMap[key]=newTestMapValue;` (why is that by reference?)

Comment: I got threads too..what happens to the old value references of the vector,map and the pointer (i just added a pointer too). I am concerned about memory leak and shallow vs deep copying. Corrected the reference.

Comment: If you have threads, you'll need to have locks around all global accesses, which will probably make your code run slowly.  What I would do in that case is use a `std::map<string , std::shared_ptr<testMap>> eeMap;` and then when you want to do something with a map, you lock the global, copy the shared_ptr to your function, then unlock the global.  Then `tMap[key]=newTestMapValue;` still works (if `newTestMapValue` is a `std::shared_ptr<testMap>`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code the "***tMap***" is a type not an instance. You cannot add with "***tMap.insert***".
First declare the global map like this:

```
tMap globalMap;
```

Then add values with:

```
globalMap.insert(make_pair ("test", *ptrTestMap ) );
```

And change values simple with [] std::map operator:

```
globalMap[key] = newMapValue;
```

Comment: I missed to instantiate but my question is when overwriting what happens to the pointers,vector and map.

Comment: The `[]` usage in your example is wrong. The parameter of the brackets  is the key, and the assigned thing is the value, not vice versa.

Comment: It is true. I inverted the statement. The right form is globalMap[key] = newTestMapValue

Comment: The defined key is a value not a pointer. By doing "globalMap[key] = newTestMapValue" a copy of "newTestMapValue" will be insert into map. Responsibility for the memory at ptrTestMap is your.

Answer (score 1):

As the question stands you do not seem to want to change the key, so it's pretty simple

```
void UpdateTestMap(testMap& newTestMapValue,string key)
{
     //tMap.erase(key); - as per the comment below this is not needed

     tMap[key] = newTestMapValue;

}
```

Seems simple and does what you seem to want

Comment: `map[key] = value` overwrites the value if the map has that key previously, so `erase()` is not needed.

Comment: @Manu343726 I though so, but was no completely sure so I decided to play it safe, thank you for clearing that up

Comment: Should I overload the assignment operator "=" here to take care of deep copying? Like in my case for the pointer,vector and the map variables?

Comment: @user2708243 **you should always meet the Rule Of Three.** Else, your class is broken.

Comment: @ciprianr see the documentation. If the key exists, `[]` just returns an lvalue-reference to the value. So assigning something to that returned reference results in overwritting the value.

Comment: @user2708243 personally I would simply build a destructor for the test map class to take care of the pointer, in the idea that the new object already takes the values of the old object and updates some of it's elements

Comment: No, no, no. You should learn the Rule Of Three. Later you should learn the resource management facilities the language has (smart pointers, containers, etc) **to avoid naked pointers and just meet The Rule Of Zero**. **If you don't meet that requeriments, the value semantics of your class are broken**.

Comment: @Manu343726 yes, you are completely right, smart pointers are the way to go now that the language has them, and the rule of zero is something that I should get a handle on

Comment: @ciprianr this is the right starting point: http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/2012/08/15/rule-of-zero.html